# Building SQLite Database with Photos

Tags: ios, swift, database, image, sqlite

I am aiming to display images collected by the user from a DetailViewController, in a UICollectionView controller. I want to use a SQLite Database, but am unsure how to start it, seeing as I already have most of my app built and established. Below see my DetailViewController (where the images are collection and displayed), ImageStore.swift (Where the images are currently being stored), and the UICollectionView controller.

ImageStore.swift:

```
class ImageStore: NSObject {

 let cache = NSCache()

 func setImage(image: UIImage, forKey key: String) {
  cache.setObject(image, forKey: key)

  let imageURL = imageURLForKey(key)

  if let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5) {
    data.writeToURL(imageURL, atomically: true)
  }
}
func imageForKey(key: String) -> UIImage? {
 if let existingImage = cache.objectForKey(key) as? UIImage {
   return existingImage
}

let imageURL = imageURLForKey(key)
guard let imageFromDisk = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imageURL.path!) else {
    return nil
}

cache.setObject(imageFromDisk, forKey: key)
return imageFromDisk
}

func deleteImageForKey(key: String) {
 cache.removeObjectForKey(key)

 let imageURL = imageURLForKey(key)
do {
    try NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtURL(imageURL)
}
catch let deleteError {
    print("Error removing the image from disk: \(deleteError)")
  }
}

func imageURLForKey(key: String) -> NSURL {
 let documentsDirectories = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
 let documentDirectory = documentsDirectories.first!

 return documentDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent(key)
}
```

DetailViewController:

```
var imageStore: ImageStore!

@IBAction func takePicture(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
 let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

  if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.Camera) {
    imagePicker.sourceType = .Camera
  } else {
    imagePicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
   }
 imagePicker.delegate = self

 presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController,  didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String: AnyObject]) {

let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage

imageStore.setImage(image, forKey: item.itemKey)

imageView.image = image

dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}
```

UICollectionView:

```
class PhotosViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
 super.viewWillAppear(animated)

 let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
 layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
 layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)

 let myCollectionView:UICollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
 myCollectionView.dataSource = self
 myCollectionView.delegate = self
 myCollectionView.registerClass(RDCellCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "MyCell")
 myCollectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
 self.view.addSubview(myCollectionView)
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
return images.count
}

var images: [UIImage] = [

]

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
 let myCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("MyCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! RDCellCollectionViewCell
 myCell.imageView.image = images[indexPath.item]
 return myCell
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
 print("User tapped on item \(indexPath.row)")
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
 super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
 // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Comment: Might be helpful: https://www.raywenderlich.com/145692/core-data-by-tutorials-updated-for-swift-3-and-ios-10

Comment: @shallowThought This link is to a book that costs over $50... any cheaper suggestions?

Comment: Wrong link. Sorry. [Here is the one I meant](https://www.raywenderlich.com/145809/getting-started-core-data-tutorial).